# Data transfer from GSP to controller without form in grails

Tags: forms, grails, controller, gsp

I want to send my user's user_id from my GSP to controller without using form or `<g:link>` tab rest, Also tell me how to send multiple data from `<g:link>` tab.

Comment: The first sentence you said you didn't want to use `<g:link>`. The second sentence you wanted to know how to send multiple values via `<g:link>`. Which is it?

Comment: These are two different questions. 1.) How to send data from GSP to controllers without any form submission or using `<g:link>`      2.) How to send multiple data from a `<g:link>` tag ..??

Comment: 1. Ajax
2. Use the `params` option of `g:link`